# How to help Eliminate simplify simultaneous equations

Tags: simplifying-expressions, algebraic-manipulation

I have a set of three moderately simple simultaneous equations that I'd like to simplify and eliminate a set of variables for (this is a simple example of a more general class of problem - but I'd like to get the simple example working before starting on the bigger ones). Asking Mathematica to `Eliminate` two of the three variables I'd like to remove and then simplifying the result gets me to the answer fairly quickly: however asking Mathematica to `Eliminate` all three of the variables at once hangs. Are there any tricks I can use to help `Eliminate` with this task, or generalisations of it?

My example has three matrices (adjoint representation of so(3) for the interested)

```
b1 = {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {0, -1, 0}}; 
b2 = {{0, 0, -1}, {0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}}; 
b3 = {{0, 1, 0}, {-1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}};
```

and then the equations are

```
{xt1, xt2, xt3} == {x1, x2, x3}.MatrixExp[t1 b1].MatrixExp[t2 b2].MatrixExp[t3 b3]
```

where I would like to eliminate the `t1`, `t2`, and `t3` variables.

Running this to eliminate `t1` and `t2` gives

```
Timing@Simplify@Eliminate[{xt1, xt2, xt3} == {x1, x2, x3}.MatrixExp[t1 b1].MatrixExp[t2 b2].MatrixExp[t3 b3], {t1, t2}]
```

> {40.375, x1^2 + x2^2 + x3^2 == xt1^2 + xt2^2 + xt3^2}

which is the correct answer. However,

```
Timing@Eliminate[{xt1, xt2, xt3} == {x1, x2, x3}.MatrixExp[t1 b1].MatrixExp[t2 b2].MatrixExp[t3 b3], {t1, t2, t3}]
```

runs forever (at least four hours on my laptop). How can I make `Eliminate`s life easier, or are there other tools I could try to solve this system of equations? (Extra information if helpful: the functional form of the reduced solution(s) to members of this class of equations will always have the same functional form in the `xt` variables and the `x` variables, although the actual functional form is unknown - I'm not sure if this can be leveraged within Mathematica to help?)

Comment: You can not eliminate 3 variables from 3 equations.

Comment: @DanielHuber Generically that's true, but not in full generality: `Eliminate[{x1, x2, x3} == {x2 + t2 + t3, x3 + t1 + t2 + 2 t3, x1 + t1 + t3}, {t1, t2, t3}]`. Your comment does suggest the OP should perhaps be content with the first attempt, checking afterwards that the third variable happened to get eliminated. That's not completely reliable either, I suspect.

Comment: Hi Michael, your 3 variables t1, t2, t3 are actually only 2 variable in disguise. They appear only in the combination t1+t3 and t2 +t3. There are only 2 independent variables.

Comment: Hi Daniel, the same is true of the OP's problem, which was my point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setup:

```
b1 = {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {0, -1, 0}};
b2 = {{0, 0, -1}, {0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}};
b3 = {{0, 1, 0}, {-1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}};
sys = {xt1, xt2, xt3} == {x1, x2, x3} . MatrixExp[t1 b1] . 
    MatrixExp[t2 b2] . MatrixExp[t3 b3];
```

---

Eliminating three variables from the three equations sequentially works quickly:

```
Quiet[
 Eliminate[
  Eliminate[
   Eliminate[sys,
    {t3}],
   {t2}],
  {t1}],
 Eliminate::ifun]

(*  -x2^2 - x3^2 + xt1^2 + xt2^2 + xt3^2 == x1^2  *)
```

---

Eliminating six variables from six equations (@Akku14's rationalization) works, too, but it takes a few seconds:

```
Eliminate[{sys,
  Sin[t1]^2 + Cos[t1]^2 == 1, 
  Sin[t2]^2 + Cos[t2]^2 == 1,
  Sin[t3]^2 + Cos[t3]^2 == 1},
 {Sin[t3], Cos[t3], Sin[t2], Cos[t2], Sin[t1], Cos[t1]}]

(*  xt3^2 == x1^2 + x2^2 + x3^2 - xt1^2 - xt2^2  *)
```

Comment: Interesting that the choice of which variable to eliminate first makes quite a difference to the speed - this approach generalises well for me though, thank you

Answer (score 2):

The quite fastest way is to use Solve, which is not sensitive if some variables are not independent of each other, add identities for Sin, Cos and eliminate all Sin und Cos at the same time.

```
Solve[{xt1 == 
Cos[t3] (x1 Cos[t2] + (x3 Cos[t1] + x2 Sin[t1]) Sin[t2]) - (x2 Cos[
     t1] - x3 Sin[t1]) Sin[t3], 
xt2 == Cos[
  t3] (x2 Cos[t1] - 
   x3 Sin[t1]) + (x1 Cos[t2] + (x3 Cos[t1] + x2 Sin[t1]) Sin[
     t2]) Sin[t3], 
xt3 == Cos[t2] (x3 Cos[t1] + x2 Sin[t1]) - x1 Sin[t2], 
Sin[t1]^2 + Cos[t1]^2 == 1, Sin[t2]^2 + Cos[t2]^2 == 1, 
Sin[t3]^2 + Cos[t3]^2 == 1}, {xt1, xt2, xt3}, {Sin[t1], Sin[t2], 
Cos[t1], Cos[t2]}]

(*   Solve::svars: Equations may not give solutions for all "solve" variables. >>

{{xt3 -> -Sqrt[x1^2 + x2^2 + x3^2 - xt1^2 - xt2^2]}, 
 {xt3 -> Sqrt[x1^2 + x2^2 + x3^2 - xt1^2 - xt2^2]}}     *)
```

And the same result for all ti with

```
Solve[{xt1 == 
Cos[t3] (x1 Cos[t2] + (x3 Cos[t1] + x2 Sin[t1]) Sin[t2]) - (x2 Cos[
     t1] - x3 Sin[t1]) Sin[t3], 
xt2 == Cos[
  t3] (x2 Cos[t1] - 
   x3 Sin[t1]) + (x1 Cos[t2] + (x3 Cos[t1] + x2 Sin[t1]) Sin[
     t2]) Sin[t3], 
xt3 == Cos[t2] (x3 Cos[t1] + x2 Sin[t1]) - x1 Sin[t2], 
Sin[t1]^2 + Cos[t1]^2 == 1, Sin[t2]^2 + Cos[t2]^2 == 1, 
Sin[t3]^2 + Cos[t3]^2 == 1}, {xt1, xt2, xt3}, {Sin[t1], Sin[t2], 
Sin[t3], Cos[t1], Cos[t2], Cos[t3]}]
```

Comment: Thank you - I had assumed Mathematica would work out the trig identities itself, good to see that it can be helped there

Answer (score 1):

If I use the [Weierstrass substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_substitution) along with `TrigExpand[]`, `GroebnerBasis[]` accomplishes the elimination pretty quickly:

```
GroebnerBasis[TrigExpand[Thread[{xt1, xt2, xt3} == {x1, x2, x3} . MatrixExp[t1 b1] .
                                                   MatrixExp[t2 b2] . MatrixExp[t3 b3]] /.
                         Thread[{t1, t2, t3} -> {2 ArcTan[u1], 2 ArcTan[u2], 2 ArcTan[u3]}]],
              {xt1, xt2, xt3, x1, x2, x3}, {u1, u2, u3}]
   {-x1^2 - x2^2 - x3^2 + xt1^2 + xt2^2 + xt3^2}
```

which is equivalent to the answer Michael gave.